# how to hit a put route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have an additional method in one of my otherwise restfull controllers called 'importdata'. As I'm actually changing the data (importing csv in the database), I understood that it should be a put route instead of get.

Initially I had

```
resource data_set do
  put 'importdata', on: :method
end
```

what I also tried is:

```
put 'data_sets/:id/importdata', "data_sets#importdata'
```

rake routes shows the route I want in both cases.

What I did when I had the method on (1st example) route in the controller was

```
redirect_to import_data_sets_path id: dataset.id
```

And with the second example:

```
redirect_to controller: "data_sets", action: "importdata", id: dataset.id
```

The message I get in both cases is:

```
No route matches [GET] "/data_sets/28/importdata"
```

Which is correct, because it's a put route. The only way I get this to work is to change the put for a get:

```
get 'data_sets/:id/importdata', "data_sets#importdata'
```

How can I get that to work on a put route? Should it be a put route in the first place?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Redirecting to a PUT makes no sense

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. What are you trying to accomplish with the redirect?

Comment: Could you tell me why not?

Comment: The redirect happens after a mapping is set between fields from the csv and the internal model fields. I can only import the data when I have that mapping. I'm happy to redirect to a get route, I just would like to understand why redirecting to a put is wrong, as I understood you should never use get when you change anything.

Comment: The `put` method is the one that accepts the data from user and then triggers whatever calls change your data. A redirect is asking the user's browser to go to a different URL. What is it that the user should be doing on this new URL, as opposed to the one that just accepted the CSV data?

Comment: @jdi, thanks for your explanation. I start to believe I don't acually need a route for this, but can just trigger the input method on the data_set model.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put you can't 'upgrade' a HTTP request issued by an user. redirects only work over GET. If the user is changing something do it through a form and make sure it's a PUT request as you're modifying an existing resource.

If the PUT is conditional there's several options, either figure out how to solve this in the UI, use an HTTP client to issue the PUT(which doesn't make sense for an local call) or extract the editing of the resource in some other kind of class and use it in the controller.

However, even if the edit is optional it makes more sense to let the user fire a PUT in the first place.

Hope that helps.